# How to remove spaces in a string after a certain character?

Tags: string, replace, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm just wondering if there is a way to replace all blank spaces after a certain character in a string.  Basically a string like;

```
str = "This is a test - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

I would like essentially remove all of the spaces after the '-'.  I understand how to do the

```
replace(str," ","")
```

but that will remove every space, and I want to keep the 'This is a test -" intact for readability to the user.  I have used

```
Instr(str,"-")
```

to get the position of that character but do not know how to then enact the replace function on the rest of the string starting from that point.

Comment: "VBScript" .. uhg. I feel pain [for you]. Does `replace` take a start index? Otherwise two substrings (get "to preserve" and "to replace" strings first) and rebuilding would work..

Comment: Just spitballing, but if the end of the first part of the string will always be unique, meaning the only '-' in the string, you could split the string on the '-' and then just remove all of the spaces in the second array from the split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would used regex but if you just want to use string functions I think this is what you are asking

```
str = "This is a test - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
chrPos = Instr(str,"-")
lStr = Left(str, chrPos + 1)
rStr = Replace(str , " " , "", chrPos+1)
wscript.echo lStr & rStr
```

The result is This is a test - 1,2,3,4,5